# How can I configure iptables for per application setup?

Tags: iptables, packaging

I am working on a project where we are building lots of micro-services. Each service is neatly packaged as an RPM.

Ideally I'd like for us to have iptables enabled on all of our machines and it would be really nice that as packages are placed on the machine they configure iptables to open the appropriate ports for themselves.

All I can think of is putting `iptables` commands with a `service iptables save` call in the post install script.

It doesn't look like iptables supports snippets (i.e. conf.d directories of config). Is there a better way or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: how about SElinux.. try `man selinux`

Comment: I would say to use ufw, but not all distros use it.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a package repository setup, and you hinted yourself at a possible solution:

Make your iptables service start script snippet-capable.

The way I have gone about this for a similar situation in the past:

- Modify init-script to implement desired behavior.
- Find out which package originally contains the init-script you just modified.
- Either create a local fork of the packet, that you update when needed,
- Or create a new package, that "overrides" that specific script with yours.
- Host the package where you host your other rpms
- Include in "micro-service-AppFooXyz.rpm" a snippet for the `conf.d`.

To make the script "snippet-capable" just lookup how some of the other init-scripts do it.

All of the steps above are an outline of what you'd need to do, and should get you started on your solution, or get you to a point, where you have a more narrow question. HTH.